# Best practices по использованию дублирующейся логики для контролов (WinForms) C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше сделать. Ситуация следующая:
Допустим, имеется две кнопки на двух разных вкладках (TabControl) предназначенных для открытия xml-файла.
Логика первой кнопки:

```
private void btnOpenConfigConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "xml files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtPathConfigConvert.Text = ofd.FileName;
        }
    }
```

Логика второй кнопки:

```
private void btnOpenConfigImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "xml files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtPathConfigImport.Text = ofd.FileName;
        }
    }
```

Как видно из примеров, отличается лишь TextBox, куда будет записываться путь.
И таких методов достаточно много для других контролов, т.к. интерфейсы на обеих вкладках во многом похожи и логика тоже во многом совпадает.

Какая практика применяется в подобных случаях?

Comment: Если Вас интересует "best practices", то начните с изучения паттерна MVC (Model-View-Controller)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вынести логику в отдельный метод, например в статическом классе

```
public static class Dialogs
{
    public string GetConfigFileName()
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "xml files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            return ofd.FileName;

        return null;
    }
 }
```

и пример вызова:

```
var path = Dialogs.GetConfigFileName();

if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
    txtPathConfigImport.Text = path;
```

Передавать в метод `GetConfigFileName` элемент управления крайне не рекомендую, так как это накладывает сильное ограничение на его использование.

---

Если у вас много похожих частей на вкладках, то возможно есть смысл подумать об определении `UserControl`.

Грязный способ - записать название textBox для которого нужно установить текст в качестве Tag для Button и уже извлекать эту информацию в обработчике события, который будет один для всех кнопок этого типа.

Answer (score 1):

```
private bool GetConfigFileName(out string aFileName)
{
  aFileName = "";
  OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
  ofd.Filter = "xml files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";

  if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    aFileName = ofd.FileName;
    return true;
  }

  return false;  
}

private void btnOpenConfigImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string fileName;
  if (GetConfigFileName(out fileName))
  {
    txtPathConfigImport.Text = fileName;
  }
}
```

или

```
private bool GetConfigFileName(TextBox aTarget)
{
  OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
  ofd.Filter = "xml files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";

  if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    aTarget.Text = ofd.FileName;
    return true;
  }

  return false;  
}

private void btnOpenConfigImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (GetConfigFileName(txtPathConfigImport))
  {
    // if needed ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, второй вариант смотрится неплохо. А что скажете по поводу использования списка контролов для каждого обработчика? Тогда была бы возможность проивзодить все операции по списку. При этом можно было бы для обеих кнопок добавить один и тот же обработчик.

Comment: @БадаловБадал Не понял про "списка контролов для каждого обработчика". Можно назначить один и тот же обработчик разным кнопкам, тогда в обработчике придется находить `TextBox` в зависимости от значения `sender`. Или Вы имеете в виду несколько обработчиков для одного клика?